# How to group list till the specific element occurs in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

How to group list till the specific element occurs

```
l= [45, 22, 11, 5, 2, 1, 20, 10, 5, 2, 1, 40, 20, 10, 5, 2, 1, 26, 13, 6, 3, 1, 32, 16, 8, 4, 2, 1]

e=1
```

My code:

```
l=[45, 22, 11, 5, 2, 1, 20, 10, 5, 2, 1, 40, 20, 10, 5, 2, 1, 26, 13, 6, 3, 1, 32, 16, 8, 4, 2, 1]
e=1 

l=[l[i:l.index(e)+1] for i in range(0,len(l))]
print(l)
```

My output:

```
[[45, 22, 11, 5, 2, 1], [22, 11, 5, 2, 1], [11, 5, 2, 1], [5, 2, 1], [2, 1], [1], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []]
```

Needed output:

```
[[45, 22, 11, 5, 2, 1], [20, 10, 5, 2, 1], [40, 20, 10, 5, 2, 1], [26, 13, 6, 3, 1], [32, 16, 8, 4, 2, 1]]
```

What mistake i made?

Comment: Can you explain the logic in words…?

Comment: @deceze OP wants to create chunks from the list that end when a sentinel value is found.

Comment: Yeah sure @deceze .....I need to group the list till  1 occures after that i need to group the list till next 1 occurs like that i need to group the list

Comment: What if `l` does not end with  `e`, though?

Comment: Sorry my English is too bad :(

Comment: @timgeb then need to return the same list

Comment: the reason your output is like that is because you loop from 0 to the whole list so after you create the first chunk, it moves to 1 so you get repetition. You can solve it by removing the chunk from the list. Also my recommendation write a clean function for it instead of trying to do a one-liner

Answer (score 3):

Basic accumulator:

```py
result = []
acc = []
for x in l:
    acc.append(x)
    if x == 1:
        result.append(acc)
        acc = []
print(result)
```

Using `groupby` and list comprehension:

```py
from itertools import groupby
[[*x, 1] for (is_valid, x) in groupby(l, key=lambda x: x != 1) if is_valid]
```

Comment: Straight forward. Note that this produces `[[0, 1]]` for `l = [0, 1, 2, 3]`. Not sure if that's the expected output.

Comment: @Alexandra Thank you bruhh I understood now!!

Comment: @Heisenberg I added to my answer an alternative using list comprehension.

Answer (score 0):

I implemented a code like this, but as far as I can say, it is not the most efficient way to solve this problem. Just for now, you can see the solution below. I will work on how to improve it.

```
import copy

l= [45, 22, 11, 5, 2, 1, 20, 10, 5, 2, 1, 40, 20, 10, 5, 2, 1, 26, 13, 6, 3, 1, 32, 16, 8, 4, 2, 1]

e=1

result_l = list()


while l != []:
    res = [i for i in l[:l.index(e)+1]]
    result_l.append(copy.deepcopy(res))
    
    index = l.index(e)+1
    for _ in range(index):
        del l[0]
    res=None


print(result_l)
```